# Associative array nesting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Having following associative array in which I want to have nesting. Not sure how to make it work best (if possible at all).

Working in Nuxt2.

```
const products = {
  Shoes: "/shoes",
  Jeans: "/jeans"
}
```

Then in my front end:

```
<div v-for="(product, text) in product" :key="text" :value="product">
```

Then call `{{ text }}`  and `{{ product }}` and works nicely.

Now in my associative array I want to have within `Shoes : /shoes` the nesting `Shoes 4 men : /shoes-men` and `Shoes 4 women : /shoes-women` and `Shoes 4 kids : /shoes-kids`.

Is that possible with my array code structure to accomplish? I tried to nest these sub-shoe-products (men, women, kids) within `Shoes` and also I tried to fix it by creating a new `const`for `Shoes` but both not working.

Comment: In JavaScript, associative arrays are called "objects".

Comment: `{ shoes: {"shoes 4 men": "/shoes-men", "shoes 4 women": "/shoes-women", ...}, ...}`. Then use nested `v-for`.